# Why is airflow logging_mixin.py adding triple stars to the log message?

Tags: logging, airflow

Below is an excerpt from an airflow task log. As soon as `logging_mixin.py` takes over logging, it adds all these stars to the log message, making it unreadable.

I looked at the source code to see what happens at that line (which is now L109 as of this writing)
https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/airflow/utils/log/logging_mixin.py#L109

```
self.logger.log(self.level, remove_escape_codes(message))
```

Looking at the docs, it says it is removing escape codes used for colors.

https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/main/airflow/utils/log/logging_mixin.py#L28

Has anyone else run into this issue? How can I prevent/fix it?

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2021-07-01 10:21:12,479] {taskinstance.py:1068} INFO - Starting attempt 1 of 3
[2021-07-01 10:21:12,482] {taskinstance.py:1069} INFO - 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[2021-07-01 10:21:12,494] {taskinstance.py:1087} INFO - Executing 

<Task(SnowflakeOperator): put_csv_file_into_internal_stage> on 2021-05-03T00:00:00+00:00
[2021-07-01 10:21:12,503] {standard_task_runner.py:52} INFO - Started process 16448 to run task
[2021-07-01 10:21:12,509] {standard_task_runner.py:76} INFO - Running: ['airflow', 'tasks', 'run', 'scv', 'put_csv_file_into_internal_stage', '2021-05-03T00:00:00+00:00', '--job-id', '24', '--pool', 'default_pool', '--raw', '--subdir', 'DAGS_FOLDER/scv.py', '--cfg-path', '/tmp/tmpqlig2mm8', '--error-file', '/tmp/tmpnmmwbq6e']
[2021-07-01 10:21:12,513] {standard_task_runner.py:77} INFO - Job 24: Subtask put_csv_file_into_internal_stage
[2021-07-01 10:21:12,557] {logging_mixin.py:104} INFO - Running <TaskInstance: scv.put_csv_file_into_internal_stage 2021-05-03T00:00:00+00:00 [running]> on host [redacted]
[2021-07-01 10:21:12,607] {taskinstance.py:1282} INFO - Exporting the following env vars:
[redacted]
[2021-07-01 10:21:12,624] {logging_mixin.py:104} WARNING - ***-***-***-*** ***L***o***g***g***i***n***g*** ***e***r***r***o***r*** ***-***-***-***
[2021-07-01 10:21:12,625] {logging_mixin.py:104} WARNING - ***T***r***a***c***e***b***a***c***k*** ***(***m***o***s***t*** ***r***e***c***e***n***t*** ***c***a***l***l*** ***l***a***s***t***)***:***
[2021-07-01 10:21:12,625] {logging_mixin.py:104} WARNING - *** *** ***F***i***l***e*** ***"***/***u***s***r***/***l***i***b***6***4***/***p***y***t***h***o***n***3***.***6***/***l***o***g***g***i***n***g***/***_***_***i***n***i***t***_***_***.***p***y***"***,*** ***l***i***n***e*** ***9***9***4***,*** ***i***n*** ***e***m***i***t***
*** *** *** *** ***m***s***g*** ***=*** ***s***e***l***f***.***f***o***r***m***a***t***(***r***e***c***o***r***d***)***
[2021-07-01 10:21:12,625] {logging_mixin.py:104} WARNING - *** *** ***F***i***l***e*** ***"***/***u***s***r***/***l***i***b***6***4***/***p***y***t***h***o***n***3***.***6***/***l***o***g***g***i***n***g***/***_***_***i***n***i***t***_***_***.***p***y***"***,*** ***l***i***n***e*** ***8***4***0***,*** ***i***n*** ***f***o***r***m***a***t***
*** *** *** *** ***r***e***t***u***r***n*** ***f***m***t***.***f***o***r***m***a***t***(***r***e***c***o***r***d***)***
[2021-07-01 10:21:12,625] {logging_mixin.py:104} WARNING - *** *** ***F***i***l***e*** ***"***/***u***s***r***/***l***i***b***6***4***/***p***y***t***h***o***n***3***.***6***/***l***o***g***g***i***n***g***/***_***_***i***n***i***t***_***_***.***p***y***"***,*** ***l***i***n***e*** ***5***7***7***,*** ***i***n*** ***f***o***r***m***a***t***
*** *** *** *** ***r***e***c***o***r***d***.***m***e***s***s***a***g***e*** ***=*** ***r***e***c***o***r***d***.***g***e***t***M***e***s***s***a***g***e***(***)***
[2021-07-01 10:21:12,625] {logging_mixin.py:104} WARNING - *** *** ***F***i***l***e*** ***"***/***u***s***r***/***l***i***b***6***4***/***p***y***t***h***o***n***3***.***6***/***l***o***g***g***i***n***g***/***_***_***i***n***i***t***_***_***.***p***y***"***,*** ***l***i***n***e*** ***3***3***8***,*** ***i***n*** ***g***e***t***M***e***s***s***a***g***e***
*** *** *** *** ***m***s***g*** ***=*** ***m***s***g*** ***%*** ***s***e***l***f***.***a***r***g***s***
[2021-07-01 10:21:12,625] {logging_mixin.py:104} WARNING - ***T***y***p***e***E***r***r***o***r***:*** ******* ***w***a***n***t***s*** ***i***n***t***
[2021-07-01 10:21:12,625] {logging_mixin.py:104} WARNING - ***C***a***l***l*** ***s***t***a***c***k***:***
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Airflow 2.1?  If so, check out this [issue](https://github.com/apache/airflow/issues/16007) and corresponding [PR](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/16057).

This should be fixed with Airflow 2.1.1 which was just recently released.